# Jersey Client Fails To Deserialize to Object

Tags: java, json, jersey, deserialization, jersey-client

So I am trying to implement a simple **Jersey Client** that hits a public API to get movie times etc..
https://api.eventcinemas.co.nz/Api/Movies/GetMovies

I have gone through tutorials on how to do this and have implemented two methods that deserialzse the JSON response into:

1. A String
2. An Object  *(POJOs)*

**The issue is this:** the JSON to String method is working correctly, printing the String to console gives me the expected result. `However when trying to deserialize to my Java Objects I am always getting null.`

I have tried a few simple things such as different dependency versions, different API calls etc but no luck. To save time I have used an online converter to take the JSON response and populate the necessary POJOs for deserialization, I have taken this to be correct.

Would someone be kind enough to point me in the right direction on why I am always getting null,  I feel like its something small or silly that I have missed. Thanks in advance!

*So starting with my pom.xml dependencies...*

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

*My Client is as follows:*

***MoviesClient:***

```
package nz.co.brownbridge.application;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

public class MoviesClient {

    protected MoviesResponse getMovieDetails() {
        /*JSON to POJO*/
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target("https://api.eventcinemas.co.nz/Api/Movies/GetMovies");
        MoviesResponse response = webTarget.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get(MoviesResponse.class);
        return response;
    }

    protected String getMovieDetailsString() {
        /*JSON to String*/
        Client client  = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target("https://api.eventcinemas.co.nz/Api/Movies/GetMovies");
        String response = webTarget.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get(String.class);
        return response;
    }

}
```

*and finally the main() class:*

**Application Class:**

```
package nz.co.brownbridge.application;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MoviesClient moviesClient = new MoviesClient();

        String stringResponse = moviesClient.getMovieDetailsString();
        MoviesResponse pojoResponse = moviesClient.getMovieDetails();

        System.out.println("Printing String Response...");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(stringResponse);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Printing POJO Response...");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(pojoResponse);


    }
}
```

**Would output the following:**

```
Printing String Response...
//super long but correct string response goes here

Printing POJO Response...

ClassPojo [Data = null, Success = null]
```

Comment: Add related code only, other wise we don't like to read

Comment: Wrong mapping. Actually NowShowing is should be "Integer[] NowShowing;" but you wrote "String[] NowShowing;"

Comment: as stated above I used a online generator for the java objects hence the poor naming conventions. It is besides the point...